# Eclipse Axis2 WSDL2Java Exception: null

Tags: eclipse, apache-axis, wsdl2java

I'm trying to generate a `Java Bean Skelleton` from a `WSDL` (actually this will happen with `Client` generation as well).

So here are the Steps I did:

- Rightclick on .wsdl -> WebServices -> Generate Java Bean Skelleton
- Select `Tomcat 7` and `Axis 2`
- Click next (In this field the Parameters fields are Empty)
- Click next, you will receive the following Error - `Exception occurred during code generation for the WSDL  : null`

This Error seems to be thrown if you check out Projects with subversive (actually in the case of our project we see this correlation).

What could be done to fix this issue?

This issue is also an open bug since 2008, [Axis2 BugTracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-4119?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only Workarround I found for this, goes as follows:

- Create a new `DynamicWebProject`
- Create a new `WSDL` (You can copy you old one or what ever you like)
- Create a new `Java Bean Skelleton` (or `Client`)

Now the `WSDL2Java` will work again for some time till it will be damaged again. You will be able to fix this by regenerate the `Java Bean Skelleton`. You won't need to create a new Project every time.

Edit:
*The actual solution to this Problem was found now. I changed my SVN-Plugin from Subversive to Subclips. Now everything works out fine.*